# Varnish is running but throws ‘Could not get hold of varnishd’ when I run varnishlog

Tags: varnish

#### Possible Solution

Possible create files with different permissions.

#### Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

Pull image for K8s from varnish docker registry
FROM varnish:6.0

Start it with the docker -compose.
Your Environment:
Version used: Varnish 6.0
Operating System and version: Ubuntu or mac os

Source of binary packages used (if any)
Built from varnish image 6.0

I faced an issue when i use varnishlog.

varnishhist & varnishlog don't work

Here the code Source of DockerFile

I fix the root privilege . Now i need to fix the varnishlog issue.
you can use any default.vcl for demo. https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl
#Varnish stage
FROM varnish:6.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpcap-dev libcap2-bin

COPY docker/varnish/conf/default.vcl /etc/varnish/default.vcl

RUN setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/varnishd
RUN usermod -a -G varnish varnishlog
RUN chown -R varnish:varnish /var/lib/varnish
USER varnish

CMD ["bash", "-c", "varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -n /tmp/varnish -p http_req_hdr_len=65536 -p http_req_size=98304 -p workspace_backend=256k -p workspace_client=256k -p shm_reclen=1024 -p max_retries=1 & varnishncsa -n /tmp/varnish -b -c -t off"]
`
i'm still suck with my issue VSM: Could not get hold of varnishd, is it running?

It looks like varnishlog is not pointing to the correct directory, or has not access to it.

Any helps would be nice

my varnish works and it is responsive but i can not  do an varnishlog.same thing with varnishncsa

Did i make something wrong in my config ?

Comment: There's clearly something wrong with the command you pasted: there's no -b or -f parameter. Maybe it's a typo.

Anyway, please add your complete Dockerfile and the docker run output to your question. This will allow me to fully inspect what is going on.

Comment: Hello @ThijsFeryn
thanks for your helps there is my docker File .
I fix the root privilege . Now i need to fix the varnishlog issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because you gave your Varnish instance a name via the `-n` parameter, you now need to use that same name when calling `varnishlog`, `varnishncsa`, `varnishtop` or `varnishstat`.

In this case this would be the `varnishlog` command:

```
varnishlog -n /tmp/varnish
```

The `-n` parameter is only useful when you run multiple Varnish instances on a single machine. I would advise you to drop `-n` as a `varnishd` runtime parameter.